# Cordova plugins manual installation

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

i tried to install [this plugin](https://github.com/Tlantic/cdv-socket-plugin) on my Phonegap app, but the object *window.tlantic.plugins.socket* seems not to be istantiated. I think it's because when i try to install that plugin with

> cordova plugin add com.tlantic.plugins.socket

it can't find it, so i have to use the entire url

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/Tlantic/cdv-socket-plugin/

and the installation works but not the plugin. If i build it from build.phonegap.com it returns

> Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: com.tlantic.plugins.socket@1

I just tried to install it manually, taking files from the github repository, but i can't make it work in any ways..could you give me some info on how to install manually a plugin in phonegap/cordova applications? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

1. Download Plugin from the github.
2. Add source files to your project
3. change config.xml and androidmanifest.xml file(take the reference of plugin.xml file in downloaded plugin folder).
4. Add plugin js code in your www folder and give the reference in html file.

Hope it will help to you

Comment: Thank you for immediate help! About changing config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml, in the first i add <plugin name="com.tlantic.plugins.socket"/> am i right? And in androidmanifest?

Comment: in your plugin folder you will find one plugin.xml file. Go through it you can find what to add in config.xml and manifest.xml file.... example <feature name="Socket">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.tlantic.plugins.socket.SocketPlugin"/>
            </feature>                                                                                                        add in config.xml file

Comment: thanks again! 
Did everything right, but still doesn't work. On build.phonegap.com it still returns "Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: com.tlantic.plugins.socket@1"..don't know if it is the plugin out to date..? Any alternatives to handle socket tcp connections?

Comment: can you come to hangouts, my mail is naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com

Comment: you shuold also add entries in /plugins/android.json (and similar for other platforms)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app before running with the new source / APK.