# How to install FastCanvas plugin for Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've written a (canvas) game in HTML5 and I'm now ready to package it for Android (and iOS at a later stage). I've looked at a few options and came to the conclusion Cordova is the way to go. I installed Cordova and was able to create an Android APK that I could test on the emulator and my Android device.

Much to my surprise, it was terribly slow, even though the original HTML5 game ran perfectly in a browser on both the emulator and the Android device. I then stumbled upon the FastCanvas plugin but I don't really understand how to install it. The Git page tells me to install the plugin using plugman:

```
plugman --platform android --project <your project folder> --plugin https://github.com/FastCanvas/FastCanvas.git
```

That doesn't work. It simply displays the help file.

Then on another page, it said I can install FastCanvas as follows:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas.git
```

That doesn't work either. If I try that, I get an error message:

```
(node:28600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch
plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
```

So I'm at a loss now. How do I install FastCanvas?

BTW, I'm on a Windows 10 machine, Cordova version is 8.0.0

**UPDATE AUG 10 2018:**

Apparently, the initial error was caused by not having installed Git on my computer. I now installed Git and I still get an error, but a different one:

```
(node:25356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch
plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json:
git+https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas.git.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
```

Still no idea what is causing this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942228/cordova-plugins-manual-installation - you can manually install a cordova plugin. I might also just try to do a brand new blank phonegap app and then manually install the fast canvas on a blank phonegap install and see how that works

Comment: Trying to install the plugin on a blank cordova project gives me the same problem.

Comment: So as you've just installed git on the computer, maybe it's not working? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I've done some more testing and got different results. If I keep editing my original question, I'm afraid it becomes a bit chaotic. Is it alright to simply delete this question and create a new?

Comment: not sure what the etiquette is on deleting vs. opening a new one. seems like node is messing up now. Is phonegap or cordova CLI installed correctly? Googled it and found some stuff - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17821 - when I have issues with the cordova CLI I manually install the plugins I want in a blank folder from scratch and it works out better for me. Not sure if thats helpful

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, FastCanvas is old and deprecated and there's no way getting that to work with the current version of Cordova/PhoneGap. Well, if there is, I wasn't able to find it after searching for almost 16 hours on the interwebs.